# Get input float from Math.cos() output value

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I wonder: in Java is there a way to tell what was the original input float value for `Math.cos()` output?

I basically need something like reverse-engineered `Math.cos()` where I only know its output value and need to compute the input float it was created from where all I really have is just the output of the `Math.cos()` function.

The value can be approximate, it does not need to be absolutely exact as it was inputted to the `Math.cos()` function.

BTW math is not my expertise so the more explanatory (with practical example) you can be the better.

Comment: Q: What's the inverse operation of "cosine"?  A: [ArcCosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#arccos).  As BeUndead said, the corresponding Java method is [Math.arccos()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos-double-).  As you probably know, the Java trig functions take arguments in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (vs. degrees).

Answer (score 2):

`cos` is not injective, so you cannot tell (precisely) what the original input was.  For example, `cos(0) = cos(2π) = 1`.  You *can* however use the [`Math#acos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos-double-) method to identify a *possible* input.

Comment: unfortunately all I know is really just the float output from the `Math.cos()` - in fact those are some of values of Matrix4 (4x4) object (.m00, .m01, .m02 etc.) produced by other application where I am trying to kind of reverse-engeneer the process to know the original float angles input values

Comment: `cos` is injective if you know an appropriate _range_ of values.  For example, if you know that the input angles can only fall in the range [0,π], then every value in the range [-1,1] has a unique mapping.  It really just depends on if you can make any assumptions about what the original values were.  If you _can't_ then there's no way to tell.

Comment: no I do not know the range as it can be any angle at all - it is part of a LEGO renderer (= LEGO bricks 3D objects)...

Comment: Right, but it's a rendering.  So do you _need_ to know if the angle is (for example) 0, or 2π?  They would both look exactly the same.  In which case you can make an assumption that you don't care what the exact value is, as long as you can find one which would give an _equivalent_.

Comment: I do not need to be absolutely exact, but I need to be accurate as I want to affect rotation of a model by rotation of some other model. Unfortunately, those angle values (x, y, z) are not in specific degrees/radians values but rather are spread as several values across the Matrix4 object (x0,x1,x2,x3,y0,y1,y2,y3,z0,z1,z2,z3,s0,s1,s2,s3).[CONTINUE BELOW]

Comment: [CONTINUATION FRO ABOVE]  I do not know how to compute it directly from those values BUT I found internal function that can rotate the whole Matrix4 so by reverse-engeneering I'd be able achieving my goal, unfortunately for that I need what I ask in my question - if there is some known method how to compute X/Y/Z angle from a Matrix4 I would be glad to know (if anyone can tell).

Comment: See section `.makeRotationY` over at https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.extractRotation (that is exactly what I have - I need compute it from exactly such scheme). BTW it is not three.js I am using, it just is EXACTLY THE STRUCTURE from my case - I am in search for that original input `theta (θ) radians` value.

Comment: That's now a different question to the original (which was just how to invert the `cos` function.  I'd consider asking a different question which details the new things (and whatever attempts you currently have to try and resolve it).